# Software for strong, random password creation?

Tags: passwords

What is a safe place/way for me to come up with a strong master password? I read another Super User post that mentioned [GRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibson_Research_Corporation), but I'm not sure if that's safe/legitimate. What's the best place for me to go to create a random, long, good password? I really doubt just typing at random is a good choice, since there are biases for where fingers go.

Comment: What would make GRC unsafe or illegitimate?

Answer (score 8):

I've used [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) for a long time. It is a password managing software, and it has a password generator built it. Simple, reliable, works.

[image]

Comment: How do you get this screen on KeePass? Are you using the version that requires .NET?

Comment: @Isxek - I got it from here. http://keepass.info/screenshots.html It doesn't require .NET.

Answer (score 3):

GRC is **definitely** legitimate. I don't think you could be any more legitimate. As far as passwords for wireless networks go (and other passwords in general where I can just pick the amount of characters I need from a very long string), I find [GRC](http://grc.com/passwords) to be the most useful place to generate these pseudo-random passwords. Otherwise, a good `head -c 8 /dev/urandom` on a linux box doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

The password managing browser add-on [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/) has a great password generator.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Roboform](http://www.roboform.com/) for a long time now, and one of the things it does is create random passwords. It has a free and paid version, and I'm not sure off the top of my head if that feature is present on both.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GetSecurePassword.com](http://www.getsecurepassword.com/).

It’s an online password generator and password checker. The site offers a free windows application for password management as well.

> [Random Password Generator](http://www.getsecurepassword.com/Download.aspx) is the excellent and easy-to-use tool for getting new secure passwords. It allows you create secure passwords in one click of a button. Create single or multiple passwords of required length. The Password Generator provides set of options that allows your choose the required complexity of the password.

[image]